# total number of columns in a matrix having at least 1 negative value

Tags: r, matrix, negative-number

I would like to find the total number of columns in a matrix of 100 rows and 1000 columns, which have at lease one negative value (a.k.a at least one value below zero). How can this be coded in Rstudio please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `colSums` on a logical `matrix` and check if the values are greater than 0, get the `sum`

```
sum(colSums(m1 < 0) > 0)
#[1] 6
```

#### data

```
set.seed(24)
m1 <- matrix(sample(-1:15, 10 * 10, replace = TRUE), 10, 10)
```